# How can I support both portrait and landscape splash screens with phonegap build?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a phonegap application that can be used in portrait or landscape mode.  We're using phonegap build, and I'd like to replace the default splash screen with our logo.  However, I can't find a way to do it so that the logo doesn't stretch when launched in either landscape or portrait mode.

Ideally I'd be able to use a 9-patch image, but I'd settle for creating portrait and landscape versions of the image.

I see a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204573/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-not-stretched-or-9patch), but I don't think I make that solution work with phonegap build.

Comment: you can use imageview with custom background by creating own xml bitmap and setting in fields to `fitXY` or another one http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html. YOu can also create `layout-portrait` and `layout-landscape` for custom view http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers (check that table) For much information which is some examples - iser SO search or google

Comment: How do I do these things within the confines of phonegap build?

Comment: splash screens are the work of the devil and not acceptable on any android app

Comment: @Merlin If you can tell me how to disable the splash screen in phonegap build, that would be fine.  What I don't want is their little plug logo showing up, and the only way I can see to do that is to provide our own instead.  Your snark is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am using 9-patch images.

Please find my detailed explanation here: [Phonegap splash screen for android: not stretched or 9patch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204573/phonegap-splash-screen-for-android-not-stretched-or-9patch/10756009#10756009)

Comment: I found that in a previous search... Can you include platform specific items like that when using phonegap build? http://build.phonegap.com

Comment: This I a java solution not a phonegap one IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug and there are no solutions for the phonegap build service. I read that some earlier phonegap-versions had no such a problem. So it may help to simply switch to an earlier version via config.xml (but I didn't try it out so far ):

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.7.0" />
```

Currently supported versions are 2.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.2.0, 2.3.0, 2.5.0, 2.7.0, and 2.9.0 (default).

Comment: I'm not working on this any more but if someone else can confirm it works/provide a working version, I'll mark as accepted.